# EasySlider and Lightbox Conflicting?

Tags: javascript, lightbox, easyslider

On my site: http://windowsphonedaily.blogspot.com/

I first noticed there was a problem when EasySlider 1.7 whenever I tried to add any javascript functions like "continuous: true". The two navigation buttons (prevBtn and nextBtn) would disappear whenever that was done, so I had to undo any changes I made. Then I realized that the simple lightbox that I use for my articles' images was not working and would just act as a normal direct link to the picture.

So I figure the problem is most likely within my site's Javascript. I usually follow examples on tutorials and guides, so I really don't know anything about how to implement more than one script without them conflicting.

I don't know much about Javascript in general, so I'm giving you a heads up that I'm a noob!

Here's what my current setup is with the Lightbox and EasySlider. I'm sure it's probably some dumb mistake I made, but any help would be appreaciated! Thank you!

```
  <!--Light Box Code Starts  Bloggerplugins.ORG-->
  <style>
    #lightbox{    position: absolute;    left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 100; text-align: center; line-height: 0;}
    #lightbox img{ width: auto; height: auto;}
    #lightbox a img{ border: none; }

    #outerImageContainer{ position: relative; background-color: #fff; width: 250px; height: 250px; margin: 0 auto; }
    #imageContainer{ padding: 10px; }

    #loading{ position: absolute; top: 40%; left: 0%; height: 25%; width: 100%; text-align: center; line-height: 0; }
    #hoverNav{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: 10; }
    #imageContainer&gt;#hoverNav{ left: 0;}
    #hoverNav a{ outline: none;}

    #prevLink, #nextLink{ width: 49%; height: 100%; background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,AAAA); /* Trick IE into showing hover */ display: block; }
    #prevLink { left: 0; float: left;}
    #nextLink { right: 0; float: right;}
    #prevLink:hover, #prevLink:visited:hover { background: url(http://lh5.ggpht.com/_u4gySN2ZgqE/SnWk89-4azI/AAAAAAAAAj8/hM0MqnVouCQ/prevlabel%5B3%5D.gif) left 15% no-repeat; }
    #nextLink:hover, #nextLink:visited:hover { background: url(http://lh6.ggpht.com/_u4gySN2ZgqE/SnWk9-mNiQI/AAAAAAAAAkA/Zg1jXV9xnQM/nextlabel%5B6%5D.gif) right 15% no-repeat; }

    #imageDataContainer{ font: 10px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; margin: 0 auto; line-height: 1.4em; overflow: auto; width: 100%    ; }

    #imageData{    padding:0 10px; color: #666; }
    #imageData #imageDetails{ width: 70%; float: left; text-align: left; } 
    #imageData #caption{ font-weight: bold;    }
    #imageData #numberDisplay{ display: block; clear: left; padding-bottom: 1.0em;    }         
    #imageData #bottomNavClose{ width: 66px; float: right;  padding-bottom: 0.7em; outline: none;}      

    #overlay{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 90; width: 100%; height: 500px; background-color: #000; }
round-color: #000; }
lute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 90; width: 100%; height: 500px; background-color: #000; }
round-color: #000; }
  </style>
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js' type='text/javascript'/>
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.3/scriptaculous.js' type='text/javascript'/>
  <script src='http://blogergadgets.googlecode.com/files/lightbox.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<!--Light Box Code Ends Bloggerplugins.ORG-->

<script src='https://sites.google.com/site/shawnhasinger/home/files/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'/>

<script src='https://sites.google.com/site/shawnhasinger/home/files/easySlider1.7.js' type='text/javascript'/>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(&quot;#slider&quot;).easySlider();
});
</script>
```

Update: I tried the fix [detailed at this website](http://designreviver.com/answers/58145/) and it fixed the Lightbox but it broke the EasySlider.

Comment: I tried fixing the problem with the fix on this site. The lightbox worked fine afterwards but the easyslider was broken. http://designreviver.com/answers/58145/

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in Javascript, but I finally got it to work after much trial and error. First, for lightbox I used Slimbox2. Then I made sure that the jquery script came before the Slimbox2 script. I put the EasySlider script last.